# Using Redis with Rails on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to launch a rails API on AWS. I have created an Elastic Beanstalk app, created a PostgreSQL RDS, and setup CodePipeline, but when I try to deploy I get an error that says "CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis". My app uses Redis to cache user login certificates, and when I run it locally I just type "redis-server" in the terminal before "rails s" and it works like a charm. I have tried creating an ElastiCache instance, but I can't figure out how to connect it to my app. I'm also unsure of whether using ElastiCache for this might be overkill, and if it might instead be better to somehow configure the app to start running Redis without it when it's deployed. Another possible solution I can think of is if there a way for me to run terminal commands on my Elastic Beanstalk app and just deploy Redis manually?

I am having a lot of trouble finding a clear explanation of what I am supposed to do to setup Redis to work with Elastic Beanstalk. Can anyone help explain this, or point me to a good resource?

Comment: How is your API code connecting to the Redis server locally? Are you using built-in Rails caching? Or are you creating a Redis instance and calling the redis server directly?

Comment: @littleforest I have one gem that is using Redis, and locally it appears it's just doing _config.redis = Redis.new_.  I am now trying to do something like this in production to connect to Elasticache, but it's still not working: _config.redis = Redis.new(url: "redis://my.elastic.cache.amazon.url.com:6379/0")_.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Does your Elastic Beanstalk instance have access to ElastiCache on port 6379 through a security group setting?

Answer (score 0):

> if there a way for me to run terminal commands on my Elastic Beanstalk app and just deploy Redis manually?

Yes, you can do this. EB allows you to write customization scripts through [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). Thus using it you could install and setup your local Redis server on the EB.

To install redis, the following `10_install_redis.config` in your `.ebextensions` config file could be used:

```
commands:
    10_install_redis:
       command: amazon-linux-extras install -y redis4.0
```

You would have to build upon the above to further setup and customize the redis server to your needs.

However, running redis on your EB instance is not a very good practice. It would be better to have it outside of your EB environment, for example on a separate EC2 instance or ECS containers if you want to save up on cost as compared to running AWS managed ElastiCache.